# How do I merge two lists, and remove duplicates, in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a source object where

```
class Source

def ==(other)
  return false if self.url == nil || other == nil
  self.url == other.url
end
```

and i have the following:

```
def self.merge_internal_and_external_sources(sources=[], external_sources=[])
    (sources + external_sources).uniq
end
```

I would like to merge the two lists, and start kicking out items from external_sources if they already exist in sources list.  I am not sure how to do this eloquently?

I also tried:

```
sources | external_sources
```

but this yields a result without the duplicates being removed because of my == comparison want to compare the 'url' attribute internally?  For example:

```
[src1] == [src2] # true
list = [src1] | [src2] 
list.size # 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "merge" (there is no `#merge` method on arrays, only on hashes), but you can simplify your code like this:

```
merged = sources | external_sources
```

To make it work with your class, you need two more methods: `#hash` (instance hash value, used for preliminary equality screening), and `#eql?`, used to confirm equality:

```
class Source
  def hash
    url.hash + 1
  end
  # Or delegate it to the url:
  # require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'
  # delegate :hash, to: :url

  def eql? other
    return false if url.nil? || other.url.nil?
    url == other.url
  end
end
```

`#hash` and `#eql?` are among the basic facilities every class should have. After adding these, `#|` and `#&` methods will start to behave on arrays of `Source` instances.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply @Boris, i've re-phrased my question, see above.

Comment: Great. Note that this answer does not solve the problem of `#==` method correctness in your class.

Comment: Gee, imagine, `#|` method actually works by _first_ comparing `#hash` values of the elements, and then confirming with `#eql?` method.

Comment: I ended doing something like?
    def ==(other)
      eql?(other)
    end

Comment: Good lesson for me. :) *#| method actually works by first comparing #hash values of the elements, and then confirming with #eql? method*.

Comment: Actually, one can learn it by diligently reading Array class docs, but I, just like you, learnt it just from some other online guy.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `#uniq` method. However, for bare `#uniq`, the same caveat applies as for `#|` method: `#hash` and `#eql?` are used in sequence to test for identical elements.

However, `uniq` [can take a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq), so

```
(sources + external_sources).uniq &:url
```

can be applied even if one is lazy to define `#hash` and `#eql?` methods for the class in question.

Comment: Nice, uniq with block gets around the necessity to define `#hash` and `#eql?` on the mother class.