# How to combine or merge a list of related objects

Tags: ruby

I have 2 collections of the same object e.g. user

```
user_list1
user_list2
```

How can I create a list that contains both lists and removes the duplicates?

```
def combine(list1, list2)
  users = []

  # ??? profit

  users
end
```

Comment: That takes pretty much literally a single character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge two lists, and remove duplicates, in ruby/rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878656/how-do-i-merge-two-lists-and-remove-duplicates-in-ruby-rails)

Comment: But you'll probably get more info from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242042/array-merge-union

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unary `|` "or" operator:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
a | b
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: each item in the array is a ActiveRecord User object.

Comment: @Blankman still works ... I tested it ... `(User.first(5) | User.first(10)).length == 10`